# Running WCF service shows directory listing instead of the service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm fiddling with a wcf service, and I've created a simple test one. When I 'run' the service, I get a directory listing in ie of the folder that the service is in. I can click on the 'myservice.svc' and it brings me to the page I'd expect, so that's ok.

I get the eerie feeling that this is wrong. Is it? If so, how is it fixed?

Comment: Sounds right to me. Once the directory listing is visible, can a client get a response from the service successfully? If so, I don't believe anything is wrong (you might need to click that .svc at first to perform some initialization, but I can't recall).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's fine. It's a side effect of the fact that your service is being hosted inside a website. Just make sure your webservice client is pointing at the svc file and you'll be set.

In the project properties of visual studio you can configure the "start" page, but this is just a debug (F5) configuration, and will have no effect on your deployment.